# How do I prevent empty merge commit messages when merging featureBranches into master?

Tags: git, merge, workflow

I'm trying to prevent essentially empty commit messages like `Merge branch 'articleScore'` from occurring when merging a branch into master.

So my question is: **how can I prevent empty featureBranch merge commit messages from occurring**?  My only thought is to

- `git checkout master`
- `git rebase featureBranch`

But I haven't seen anyone else mention that solution (or this problem).

And BTW, I've spent a few hours researching this, and it's different from `git pull --rebase` and `git --no-commit` which does something entirely unrelated.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty merge commit messages"? You don't like the auto-generated commit messages, or you don't like the merge commits? Your problem is not clear, and neither is your desired outcome.

Comment: I don't like the ones I mentioned in the question.  `Merge branch 'featurebranch'`.  I may have found [a/the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358418/how-to-avoid-merge-commit-hell-on-github-bitbucket), though it's still a bit cryptic for me.

Comment: I just want to merge the two without having a meaningless commit message in our log

Comment: No, we don't really want there to be a commit message at all ideally.  The answer I linked to has it. Not sure if I should close or not.  But the answer is you do `git merge --ff-only featureBranch` as noted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358418/how-to-avoid-merge-commit-hell-on-github-bitbucket)

Comment: I see. It's not about the *message*, you didn't want the *merge commit*. Yes it's a duplicate of the answer you linked.