# Avoid merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' on single-user git repositories

Tags: git, macos, intellij-idea, merge

I know there are several questions concerning multiple merge remote-tracking
branch `origin/master` commits, albeit they all seem to address cases where
multiple users are using a Git repository. However, in my case I’m using the
repository alone, and still have those merge commits on almost every push. See
the screenshot for an example. These commits were commited and pushed
consecutively from the same machine by the same user.

> [image: DAG]

How can I stop these unnecessary merge events?

Comment: Did you check that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358418/how-to-avoid-merge-commit-hell-on-github-bitbucket . It should solve your problem.

Comment: hm ja, rebasing would be an option, but why do the repositories diverge in the first place?

Comment: You get those merge messages when the origin/master repo is not in sync with your local working directory.  You need to "sync" _before_ adding new code or rebase.