# Why I need to perform git REBASE each time after a commit is being pushed by another developer?

Tags: git, gitlab

- We have a default branch named `development`
- I have pushed or merged my branch to the development branch
- After that I've merged another developer's codebase to the development branch
- Then I am attempting to pull from the development branch, but it is rejecting
- Without Git Rebase I can not run git pull command

My question is: On that scenario, it should prompt us to merge my local branch to the development branch. But instead it prompting me to run git rebase using `git pull origin development --rebase`

Comment: You do not *have* to rebase, you can also merge the remote changes into your local changes or vice versa.

Comment: You probably set `git config pull.rebase true`. You want to set it to false to merge instead of rebase

Comment: You can also run [`git pull --no-rebase`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---no-rebase) to merge instead of rebase once without setting the default

Comment: The point is: you have to do *something*: either merge or rebase. The choice is yours.

Comment: [In three months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358418/how-to-avoid-merge-commit-hell-on-github-bitbucket)